# Random, and not same with last 10. (Java)

Tags: java, random

I'm new here..
I want to make a code to remember the last 10 numbers and to be not same.

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(getRandomNumber());
}

public static int getRandomNumber()
{
    int randomN = 0, rand = Rnd.nextInt(20);
    while (nums.size() == 10)
    {
        nums.remove(nums.get(0));
        continue;
    }
    if (!nums.contains(rand)) 
    {
        nums.add(rand);
        randomN = rand;
    }
    else getRandomNumber();

    return randomN;
}
```

when the array reach 10 values the first one will be deleted ..  I hope you understand what I want :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

class main{
    public ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    public Random generator;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Calling Start
        (new main()).start();
    }

    public void start(){
        nums =  nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        generator = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
            add(generator.nextInt(20));
            print();
        }
    }

    public void add(int newNumber){
        // Check by iterating if i is already in nums
        Iterator it = nums.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            if(newNumber == (Integer) it.next())
                return;     // i is already in our list
                            // so get out add()
        }

        if(nums.size() == 10){
            int forward = nums.get(0);

            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
                // Move numbers back 1 position
                nums.set(i-1,forward);
                // Save next number in forward
                forward = nums.get(i);
            }
        }

        nums.add(newNumber);
    }

    public void print(){
        String str = "";
        Iterator it = nums.iterator();

        if(it.hasNext()){
            str += "num: [ " + (Integer) it.next();
        }

        while(it.hasNext()){
            str += " , " + (Integer) it.next();
        }

        str += " ]";

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a class 'main' is confusing.  Especially one that contains a main() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [ArrayDequeue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and when the length grows to more than 10, you simple remove the items from the tail.

Comment: The semantics you want (first-in-first-out) are most closely expressed by the interface Queue. ArrayDeque is one implementation -- LinkedList (mentioned below) is another.

Comment: @Vance Maverick, yeah I finally used ArrayDeque

Answer (score 0):

I would either use a circular array or a linked list for this. Depending on what you plan to use the list of numbers for.

Comment: If you're using FIFO to determine which question is asked, either would do as you would add to the back of the array/linked list and remove from the front. If you need to access random elements i would go with the array. If you are using FIFO I would go with the linked list simply because its easier. It saves you the work of keeping track of the front and end indices, which you would need to do in a circular array.